# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Goes Off Screen

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4. My header is Navbar and I have a dropdown button at the end.
The list drops down but the words go off page and cannot be read.  How do I resolve this, please?

Please see https://dreamwebdesigns.co.uk

Answer (score 1):

Change your dropdown-menu div:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

to:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
```

Answer (score 0):

*Update:
In Bootstrap 5 use [**dropdown-menu-end**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/#alignment-options), instead of dropdown-menu-right:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```